# Type Class for Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, chisel

I need to implement a custom type class for Complex DSP and Complex Ring operations. I'm aware about DspTools project, but purposely want to exclude it from consideration.

I've got a hardware module, which I want to instantiate with diff type classes: UInt, SInt, FixedPoint, Real and Complex(FixedPoint, FixedPoint).

Here's my minimal class:

```
class Complex[A <: Data, B <: Data] (val re:A, val im:B) extends Bundle {
  override def cloneType: this.type = new Complex(re, im).asInstanceOf[this.type]
}

object Complex {    
  def apply[A <: Data, B <: Data](re:A, im:B) = new Complex(re, im)  
  implicit def UInt2Complex(re:UInt, im:UInt) = Complex(re,im)
}
```

When I instantiate this with different data types from Chisel3.Core, the code compiles and works.
However, when I try to do :

```
import chisel3.core.{FixedPoint => FP}
...

  val inType  = Complex ( FP(20.W,10.BP), FP(20.W,10.BP))
  val outType = Complex ( FP(20.W,10.BP), FP(20.W,10.BP))
...
```

I get the code compiled, but FIRRTL emits an error:

[info] using --backend-name verilator
[info]   chisel3.core.Binding$RebindingException: Attempted reassignment of binding to chisel3.core.FixedPoint@d
[info]   at chisel3.core.Data.binding_$eq(Data.scala:250)

What's wrong with this? How to fix the issue?

Comment: I wonder if part of your problem is that your binary point is larger than the width of your wires. While this possibility was discussed during the implementation of FixedPoint I don't think it was explicitly coded for or tested

Comment: Sorry Chick, that was a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that Chisel needs fresh clones of any `Data` when it recursively calls cloneType, and you're simply passing `re` and `im` to the `Complex` constructor resulting in the exact same objects. Put a little more concretely:

```
val a = Complex(UInt(8.W), UInt(8.W))
val b = a.cloneType
a.re eq b.re // This will be true and it *must* not be
```

This is kind of an age old problem that we don't have a great solution to, in your case, you should call `.cloneType` on `re` and `im` in `Complex.cloneType`

I know you aren't using DSPTools, but it can still provide a reference and they do that: https://github.com/ucb-bar/dsptools/blob/fe8f9d08987f3a403f6281ba4face1c26b627b71/src/main/scala/dsptools/numbers/chisel_concrete/DspComplex.scala#L75

Comment: worked like a charm! Pls send me your card number - I'll appreciate your answers with green presidents :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the actual minimalistic implementation, which worked for me. @jkoenig pointed me to the right direction. Thanks a lot!

```
class Complex[A <: Data, B <: Data] (val re:A, val im:B) extends Bundle {
  override def cloneType: this.type = new Complex(re.cloneType, im.cloneType).asInstanceOf[this.type]
}

object Complex {

  def apply[A <: Data, B <: Data](re:A, im:B):Complex[A,B] = {
    val real  = re.cloneType
    val imag  = im.cloneType
    new Complex(real,imag)
  }  
}
```